# Sql script foreignn key mapping error magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i have 2 tables **spen_recipe** and **spen_recipe_type**

**spen_recipe** has columns

1) recipe_id  PK

2) recipe_type FK

**spen_recipe_tpye** has columns

1) recipe_type_id  PK

No i have to map recipe_type (FK) from 1st table to recipe_type_id (PK) in 2nd table.

For that i have my script as :

```
->addForeignKey(
$this->getFkName('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe','recipe_type', 'vendor_recipe/spen_recipe_type','recipe_type_id'),
    'recipe_type',
$this->getTable('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe_type'),
    'recipe_type_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
)
```

**updated full code:**

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
->newTable($installer->getTable('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe'))
->addColumn('recipe_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'identity'  => true,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Recipe ID')
->addColumn('user_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'USer ID')
->addColumn('recipe_name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Recipe Name')
->addColumn('recipe_title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'User ID')
->addColumn('spen_recipe_type', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Recipe Type')
->addColumn('cooking_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Cooking Time')
->addColumn('preparation_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Preparation time')
->addColumn('serving_to', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Serving to')
->addColumn('recipe_desc', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Recipe Description')
->addColumn('recipe_photo', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Recipe Photo')
->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Created At')
->addColumn('modified_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Modified At')
->addColumn('published_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Published At')
 ->addForeignKey(
    $this->getFkName('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe','recipe_type', 'vendor_recipe/spen_recipe_type','recipe_type_id'),
        'recipe_type',
    $this->getTable('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe_type'),
        'recipe_type_id',
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE,
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE
) 
->setComment('Spen Recipe Table');
```

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

I am getting Undefined column "recipe_type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying to `addForeignKey` to the `spen_recipe` table and not to the `spen_recipe_type`. Normally, you should receive that error message in case you try executing `addForeignKey` on the second table (`spen_recipe_type`) which does not contain the `recipe_type` column.

Comment: Yes recipe_type (spen_recipe table) is the foreign_key for recipe_type_id (spen_recipe_type table)

Comment: I hope its not necessary to give the same name "recipe_type" in spen_recipe_type table also

Comment: Can you add the entire code of your installer file?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Hey, but in all your columns for the `spen_recipe` table, I cannot find the column `recipe_type`. I can only see `spen_recipe_type` -> Is this the field you want to make fk?

Comment: That's way you get the error `I am getting Undefined column "recipe_type"`,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47918/discussion-between-tudor-and-sachin-s).

Comment: got it buddy ! thanks, had my spen_recipe_type column name mistake..changed it to recipe_type